# The Halting Problem -- why do we do the opposite?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, computability, computational-geometry

I don't really get why `testhalt` doesnt exist based on the proof that some program, ie `turing`, called on `testhalt` does the opposite of `testhalt`.
Below is a definition for `testhalt`
[image]
And one for `turing`.

[image]

How come we absolutely must, in `turing`, do the opposite of `testhalt`? (meaning loop if `testhalt` halts, for example)

Answer (score 1):

The point isn't that $\mathsf{TURING}$ does the opposite of $\mathsf{TESTHALT}$, but rather that - when fed a judiciously chosen input - it does the opposite of **itself**. Since this is blatantly impossible, $\mathsf{TURING}$ can't exist and therefore $\mathsf{TESTHALT}$ can't exist either.

Specifically, consider what happens when we feed $\mathsf{TURING}$ its own index $\tau$. We get that $\mathsf{TURING}(\tau)$ halts iff $\mathsf{TESTHALT}(\tau,\tau)$ says "no" (by definition of $\mathsf{TURING}$) iff $\mathsf{TURING}$ does not halt on input $\tau$ (by assumption on $\mathsf{TESTHALT}$). This self-contradictory behavior ("I halt on input $\tau$ ifff I don't halt on input $\tau$") is what concludes the argument.